# What pill is this?

Tags: riddle

This guy I know bought a toy electronic lizard that worked with an app on his phone. He had fun making the lizard run around the house. But after a few days it didn't work any more. I told him there is a pill for that. What kind of pill, he wanted to know.

Comment: A bitter pill. Or the red-pill, considering the status of reptilians in the conspiracy ecosystem

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe the pill is

> for e-reptile dysfunction.

Comment: You've been talking to my girlfriend!

Comment: this is hilarious!

Answer (score 6):

The not-very-clever answer would be that the lizard is

> simply out of battery and needs a new pill battery.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be an attempt to push

> Apple ("A-pill") iPhone